# Find the surface area using volume

Tags: volume, area

A water tank has a surface area of $8000$ cm² and a capacity of $51.2$ liters. Find the surface area of a similar water tank which has a capacity of $21.6$ liters.

Comment: Area should be cm $^2,$ right?

Comment: sorry thx for the notification

Comment: Its a cylindrical,cuboid,spherical water tank? What kind of shape it is..

Comment: the question does not state it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Hint***:

If both tanks are *similar*, it means their *aspect ratio* $^1$ is the same. That means that $V/A$ remains constant for each tank, where $V$ is volume and $A$ is the surface area.

---

$^1$, I thinks there's another name for this. Maybe, *characteristic length*.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Surface area $\propto$ side$^2$ and capacity $\propto$ volume $\propto$ side $^3$

$\implies$ Surface area $^3\propto$ capacity $^2$

Answer (score 0):

The volume is scaled by the factor $\frac{1}{2}$. So the linear dimensions are scaled by the factor $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{1/3}$. So surface area is scaled by the factor
$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2/3}$.